# SF Tessellation not working

Tags: r, sf, tesselation

I am fairly new to using sf and R in general and I keep running into a frustrating problem. I'm using the method outlined in [this tutorial](https://urbandatapalette.com/post/2021-08-tessellation-sf/) and I am getting the following messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In st_is_longlat(x) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
2: In st_is_longlat(x) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
3: In sf::st_is_longlat(shp2) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
4: In sf::st_is_longlat(shp) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
```

It assumes that all of my data points are in the same section of the grid and I'm not sure how to fix it.
My point map works fine and has all my points where it's supposed to be, but my grid doesn't work (pictured)[[image]] [image]
I can get it to work fine with the example hkdataset it only seems to have an issue with [my dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eJwbngT-isiWd6CtQcs9ZIV13Bd2Dr77ixlRkFwWyT0/edit?usp=sharing) I think it's an issue with the formatting?

Here's my code:

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
a_striatus <- read_csv("accipiter_striatus_test.csv")
#want this to be an sf object instead of a dataframe
test_data1 = subset(a_striatus)
test_points1 = test_data1 %>%
  #filter out any missing long/lat values
  filter(!is.na(decimalLatitude) & !is.na(decimalLongitude)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"),crs = 4326, remove = FALSE)
mapview_test_points = mapview(test_points1, cex = 3, alpha = .5, popup = NULL)
mapview_test_points
#fishnet grid
area_fishnet_grid = st_make_grid(test_points1, c(150,150), what = "polygons", square = TRUE)
#to sf and add grid ID
fishnet_grid_sf = st_sf(area_fishnet_grid) %>%
  # add grid ID
  mutate(grid_id = 1:length(lengths(area_fishnet_grid)))
#count number of polygons in each grid
fishnet_grid_sf$n_colli = lengths(st_intersects(fishnet_grid_sf, test_points1))
fishnet_count = filter(fishnet_grid_sf, n_colli > 0)
tmap_mode("view")

map_fishnet = tm_shape(fishnet_count) +
  tm_fill(
    col = "n_colli",
    palette = "Reds",
    style = "cont",
    title = "Accipiter striatus observations",
    id = "grid_id",
    showNA = FALSE,
    alpha = 0.5,
    popup.vars = c(
      "Accipiter striatus observations: " = "n_colli"
    ),
    popup.format = list(
      n_colli = list(format = "f", digits = 0)
    )
  ) +
  tm_borders(col = "grey40", lwd = 0.7)

map_fishnet
```

Comment: Hard to tell without some details of your data, because the warnings seem related to the coordinates in your data. Which function is actually producing the warning? Do you have points very far north because Web Mapping doesn't like locations further north than 85.06 degrees. What does "my grid doesn't work" mean? Are you expecting to see a grid of points in one of those maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your grid contain one quite big polygon:

```r
a_striatus <- read.csv("~/Downloads/accipiter_striatus_test - accipiter_striatus_test.csv") |>
  subset(!is.na(decimalLatitude) | !is.na(decimalLongitude)) |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), crs = "EPSG:4326")

area_fishnet_grid <-  sf::st_make_grid(a_striatus, c(150,150), what = "polygons", square = TRUE) |>
  sf::st_as_sf()
sf::st_bbox(area_fishnet_grid)
#>      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#> -79.51667  44.99854  70.48333 194.99854
```

Here you got an issue with grid size. `c(150,150)` corresponds to 150° x 150° – have a look on bounding box coordinates. If you would like to have the grids in meters/kilometers, please transform your data to any metric CRS. Let's make the grid a bit smaller (1x1 ° in example below):

```r
area_fishnet_grid <-  sf::st_make_grid(a_striatus, c(1,1), what = "polygons", square = TRUE) |>
  sf::st_as_sf()

sf::st_bbox(area_fishnet_grid)
#>      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#> -79.51667  44.99854 -56.51667  55.99854

tmap::tm_shape(area_fishnet_grid) +
  tmap::tm_borders() +
  tmap::tm_shape(a_striatus) +
  tmap::tm_dots() +
  tmap::tm_basemap()
```

[image]

```r
area_fishnet_grid <- area_fishnet_grid |>
  dplyr::mutate(grid_id = dplyr::row_number())

area_fishnet_grid$n_colli <- lengths(sf::st_intersects(area_fishnet_grid, a_striatus))
area_fishnet_grid <- area_fishnet_grid |>
  subset(n_colli > 0)

tmap::tm_shape(area_fishnet_grid) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(fill = "n_colli",
                    fill.scale = tmap::tm_scale_continuous_log1p(values = "Blues"),
                    fill_alpha = 0.3,
                    col_alpha = 0.4) +
  tmap::tm_shape(a_striatus) +
  tmap::tm_dots(size = 0.05) +
  tmap::tm_basemap()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This fixed it, thanks so much! :)